# I can't center a button in my subview, I have been stuck for weeks now (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building an app with cocoa pods ( Shuffle ) where there is a cardStack (tinder style) with each card containing a word in the center. I am trying to add a button to each card with the code below, but while I managed to programmatically add the button, I cannot center it: when I use "button.center = card.center", the button remains at coordinates (0,0) of the "card view". I have attached a screenshot where you can see the rounded white button in the upper right corner at the ( 0,0 ) coordinates as said before. What am I getting wrong? It's supposed to be quite elementary but I am stuck.

```
import UIKit
import Shuffle


class CardsViewController: UIViewController, SwipeCardStackDataSource, SwipeCardStackDelegate {
    
    let cardStack = SwipeCardStack()
    var actualIndex : Int = 0

    var showingBack = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(cardStack)
        cardStack.frame.size.height = view.frame.size.height - 180
        cardStack.frame.size.width = view.frame.size.width
        cardStack.center.y =  CGFloat(cardStack.frame.size.height/2)
        cardStack.center.x =  CGFloat(cardStack.frame.size.width/2)
        cardStack.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y + 78)
        cardStack.dataSource = self
        
//        BUTTON
        
        
        
//        NAVIGATION BAR TRANSPARENT
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        
        
//        CENTRAL BUTTON

    }
    
    
    func card(fromImage word: String) -> SwipeCard {
        let card = SwipeCard()
        card.swipeDirections = [.left, .right]
        for direction in card.swipeDirections {
          card.setOverlay(CardOverlay(direction: direction), forDirection: direction)
        }
        card.content = CardContentView(withWord: word)
        card.footer = CardFooterView(withTitle: "", subtitle: "")
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let button = UIButton()
         button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.width/2
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.backgroundColor = .init(white: 1, alpha: 1)

        button.center = card.center
        
        card.addSubview(button)
            return card
    }
    
    
    func cardStack(_ cardStack: SwipeCardStack, cardForIndexAt index: Int) -> SwipeCard {
        let  theCard = card(fromImage: cardWords[actualIndex].word)
        actualIndex = actualIndex + 1
        return theCard
    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmTok.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `card` frame is not yet valid when you're trying to add your button.

I haven't used this "Shuffle" pod, but a quick look tells me you want to be using auto-layout / constraints instead of trying to set the button's position based on the frame center.

Try it like this:

```
func card(fromImage word: String) -> SwipeCard {
    let card = SwipeCard()
    card.swipeDirections = [.left, .right]
    for direction in card.swipeDirections {
        card.setOverlay(CardOverlay(direction: direction), forDirection: direction)
    }
    card.content = CardContentView(withWord: word)
    card.footer = CardFooterView(withTitle: "", subtitle: "")
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    
    // changes begin here...
    let button = UIButton()
    // use auto-layout / constraints
    //button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
    
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // add button to card
    card.addSubview(button)

    // button width = 70, height equalTo width
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.0).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    // center it in the card view
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: card.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    
    // NOTE: you can only have one of the next options active
    //       at a time
    
    // if you want the button centered vertically in the card
    //button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: card.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
    // or, if you want the bottom of the button to be
    //  a specific distance (such as 30-pts)
    //  from the bottom of the "card"
    //button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: card.bottomAnchor, constant: -30.0).isActive = true

    // or, if you want the vertical center of the button to be
    //  a percentage distance of the height of the "card"
    //  such as "75% of the distance to the bottom"
    //      we have to use a different constraint initialization
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: button,
                       attribute: .centerY,
                       relatedBy: .equal,
                       toItem: view,
                       attribute: .bottom,
                       multiplier: 0.75,
                       constant: 0.0).isActive = true


    // frame is not yet valid, so use 70 / 2
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 35.0 //button.frame.width/2
    
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.backgroundColor = .init(white: 1, alpha: 1)
    
    return card
}
```

***Edit** - added 2 additional options for the vertical position of the button. See the comments in the above code.*

Depending on how you have your `SwipeCard` and `CardContentView` classes setup, you may need to be adding the button to the content view instead of to the card itself (you haven't shown those classes, so difficult to guess).

As a side note: You really should be modifying either your `SwipeCard` class or your `CardContentView` class and adding your button there...

Comment: Thank you so much!! That helped! What if I would like to lower the button a bit (so that to pin it in the lower area of the card)?

Comment: @user7618238 - I **Edited** my answer and added 2 more options for controlling the vertical position of the button. See the comments in the code.